# email address icon on task bar

Tags: email

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and found my email address as an icon on the taskbar. It's the second icon from the bottom in the below screenshot. When I try to open it the message says 'Something went wrong.'  How do I get rid of this icon?

[image]

Comment: That is unexpected behavior other users may not know. You may want to post a screen shot of this phenomenon. That may be some specific application you have installed. Is this an upgrade of a previous install, or is this a fresh install (i.e., fully new). Add information to your actual question: use "edit".

Comment: try using gnome tweaks or install gnome

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the "email address icon" on the favorites bar (after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04), go to your Ubuntu "Settings," then go to "@ Online Accounts" and next remove the accounts that display the error triangle.  That should do it.